# How to get the child projects consolidated data in parent project details in Rally SOAP APIs?

Tags: web-services, soap, rally

I am fetching data from Rally using its SOAP APIs. I have one Parent project with multiple child projects working on the same release. When I am fetching The Release of the parent project, it give me wrong statistics without consolidating the story points of child projects. Is there any method/object in Rally's API where I could get the consolidated release data of the child projects also when I am fetching a Parent Release data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that Release-based rollups are handled within Rally is that typically a Release is setup at the Parent project level, and there is a check-box in the UI to copy the Release to all Child projects, using identical name and start/end dates. So you would end up actually having multiple Release objects of identical name and timeboxes, at the parent and all child projects.

If you are wanting to aggregate statistics on Stories within a Release, and have followed the Parent/Child Release naming consistency convention above, that you can do a query on HierarchicalRequirement using queryString = "(Release.Name = \"My Release"\"); and get back a collection of Stories whose aggregate stats (say, Plan Estimate) should match your roll-up statistics that you desire.

Comment: I should add that - if you are wanting to aggregate statistics on Stories within a Release, and have followed the Parent/Child Release naming consistency convention above, that you can do a query on HierarchicalRequirement using queryString = "(Release.Name = \"My Release"\"); and get back a collection of Stories whose aggregate stats (say, Plan Estimate) should match your roll-up statistics that you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually your comment answers the question. But I couldn't understand why Rally doesn't roll up child data when an Release of Parent Project is fetched, it could have made life simpler.